# how to return values from one class to another?

Tags: c#, class, return

I'm making a program that has three classes:

1. Output class receives data from other two classes, writes to two new strings, combines with special formatting to another string and outputs it
2. AidaF class has a method that returns a value(a string) every second
3. GmailF class has a method that returns a value(a string) every minute or so

so i tired using `return string;` to return the data from classes 2 and 3 to the first class but that just returns the value to the current class, not to the first class.

Here is this code I'm working on, slimmed down a lot though. but basics are there.

```
namespace Final
{
    public class Output
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(gml + aida);
        }
    }

    public class AidaF
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public static void AMain()
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }


        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...
            reader.ReadToFollowing("value");
            aida.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString()).Append(",");
            return aida;
            ...
        }
    }

    public class GmaillF
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer gTimer;

        public static void GMain()
        {
            gTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200000);
            gTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent1);
            gTimer.Interval = 200000;
            gTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent1(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckMail();
        }

        public static string CheckMail()
        { 
          ...
          gml.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString()).Append(",");
          return gml;
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but you seem to want to treat classes as procedures/functions... they really are not, practically or semantically. :-P

Comment: i want to return values from classes 2 and 3 so that class 1 can do something with them.

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent the "observable collection" pattern? That is, a collection is normally thought of as something you "pull" information from, one thing at a time, like a list of customers. An observable collection *pushes* information at consumers that are interested in it.

Comment: Classes are not things that "return" values; classes *represent kinds of things*. A class "Newspaper" represents the class of all objects that are newspapers. *Methods* return values.

Comment: Eric Lippert is exactly right. A read-up on basic object-oriented principles may help...

Comment: ok thanks, i was advised by another person that this would be a good approach to do it(2 classes for the two different parts then a 3rd for output.)

Comment: this is where i was advised: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314638/how-to-merge-c-code-of-two-similar-but-separate-programs/7314983#7314983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the exposed static methods from the calling class in order to get this to work, so for example your main would look more like this:

```
public static void Main() {
Console.WriteLine(GmailF.CheckMail() + AidaF.OnTimedEvent());
}
```

I'm just guessing that CheckMail and OnTimedEvent are the strings you are trying to return.  Both CheckMail and OnTimedEvent have to be public static strings for the above to work.